# how to leftalign buttons in div?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

i am trying to align a few buttons in my asppanel. So but1 and but3 need to be left aligned?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .flo
        {
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Panel CssClass="fl0" ID="pnl1" runat="server" Style="background-color: #DDDDDD;
            border: solid 1px black; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;" Width="120px"
            Height="42px">
            <div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: -28px; float:left">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="but1"  />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="but2"  Visible="true" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="but3"  Visible="true" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where did your doctype disappear to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
   div style="text-align:left; padding:10px 0 0 0;">
           <div style="padding:3px 0 0 0; height: 36px;">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="but1"  />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="but2"  Visible="true" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="but3"  Visible="true" />  
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: yeah.. since buttons are inline-block elements by default,text-align:left should do the trick